# How to style the HTML5 video Chrome play button and timeline thumb

Tags: css, html

I styled the video tag with

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    background-color: rgb(226, 30, 38);
}
```

It works great - although I've disabled some options - but I can't colorize the timeline thumb or the play button.

Comment: here is a good tutorial : http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos

Comment: @Nevermore that’s about providing your own, custom controls - but I think this question is about styling the _default_ controls provided by the browser.

Comment: yes i know ro use jquery pr something else, but I want to ise css

Comment: I tried this:    video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline::-webkit-media-slider,
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline::-webkit-media-slider-thumb,
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline::-webkit-slider-thumb,
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider::-webkit-media-slider-thumb{
    background-color: #07dd00;  
    background: #07dd00;  
    color: #000000;
}
but didn't work!

Comment: this colors timeline and the area under timeline